# Why does auto weight paint do a poor job?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

I am having an issue where the auto generated weight paint does not match the bones of the model. I have looked up why this may be the case and tried a few things such as applying transformations, scales, and fixing the origin; however, none of this has helped create a good weight paint generation. I know that I will have to go though and manually fix some of the oddities, but the current auto generated paint is just so far off I fell that I have done something wrong.

I have a link to the project below. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q7zNqLW9FtHhBSher1wjErQTZP7kQvf4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: it may be because your normals are flipped but recalculate doesn't seem easy to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @moonboots for the fix. My normals were flipped which was causing the weight paint algorithm to act funny. It was a quick fix to fix all the normals. All I had to do was select the normals that were facing the wrong direction and recalculate them using "shift + N". After fixing the normals I reparented the armature and it did a much better job of assigning weights.